# Getting "error writing request body to server "

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey

I try to upload an image and use a RestService with jersey. If I test My Rest Service it will works perfectly but if debug the test i get these error message. Have somebody any idea?

Stack Trace:

```
testCreateImage(com.myrest.api.rest.v1.LoyalitiyResourceTest)  Time elapsed: 1.829 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to serverat sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3174)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:90)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeTo(ReaderWriter.java:115)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeTo(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:76)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:103)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:64)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:213)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:81)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:537)
at com.myrest.api.rest.v1.LoyalitiyResourceTest.testCreateImage(LoyalitiyResourceTest.java:318)
```

The jerey annotated class.

```
@PUT
@RolesAllowed({"Registered", "Author", "Editor", "Publisher", "Manager", "Administrator", "Super Users"})
@Path("/{id}/image/{type}")
@Consumes("image/*")
public Response setImage(@Context SecurityContext context, @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
       @PathParam("id") Integer id, @PathParam("type") String type, InputStream imageStream) {
  final String mn = "setCardImage";
  LOGGER.entering(SOURCE_CLASS, mn);

  try {
     getService().setCardImage(getCurrentUser(context.getUserPrincipal()), id, type, imageStream);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
     LOGGER.throwing(SOURCE_CLASS, mn, e);
     WebApplicationException ex = new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
     throw ex;
  }

  LOGGER.exiting(SOURCE_CLASS, mn);
  return Response.created(uriInfo.getRequestUri()).build();
```

}

JUnit Test Here at the line

ClientResponse response = wr.put(ClientResponse.class, testLENA);

Is the Error.

```
@Test
public void testCreateImage() {
  //create Image
  final String url  ="/loyality/4/image/front";
  WebResource webResource = resource();
  webResource.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("admin", "admin"));

  File testLENA = new File("src/test/resources/images/lena.png");
  Builder wr = webResource.path(url).header("open-api", "test").type("image/png");   
  ClientResponse response = wr.put(ClientResponse.class, testLENA);
  Assert.assertEquals(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED, response.getStatus());
  Assert.assertNotNull(response.getEntity(String.class));
}
```